# How to play SWF videos

Tags: video, swf

I have swf flash videos on my USB that I can't get to run in Ubuntu.
In Windows I was using a program called MpcStar / TigerPlayer.

I tried gnash SWF player in Ubuntu, but problem is that it doesn't let me control the video and it's very frustrating. It only plays it.

Comment: Are you sure that file contains a Flash video and not a whole Flash application? I used to have some Flash-based games downloaded as `.swf` files that will only work in an actual Flash runtime environment like in a web browser with Flash plug-in (or compatible). If that's the case you can open the file in a web browser.

Answer (score 2):

VLC can play .swf videos.  You can install it from the Ubuntu Software Center.

Comment: I tried...but it doesn't work. It's too buggy and it also doesn't let me control the flash videos for some reason.

Comment: Interesting that you say it's buggy.  It's pretty much the gold standard video player.

Comment: I agree. It's excellent for every video but SWF videos. Try it yourself and you'll see. I presonally use it for everything else.

Answer (score 0):

I have VLC version 2.2.1 on Ubuntu 14.04. I have swf videos. When I open a swf file, it plays momentarily then fails. This is my personal experience. I just upgraded to VLC 2.2.1. I hope other posters make comments from personal experience/knowledge, not just saying things because it seems to be true.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick HTML code that plays a swf file called "lesson1.swf". In a pinch you can modify it for your own needs:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Play swf file</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="swfobject.js"></script>
        <style type="text/css">

            body 
            {
                background-color: #1a1a1a;
                font: .8em/1.3em verdana,arial,helvetica,sans-serif;
                text-align: center;
            }
            #media
            {
               margin-top: 5px;
            }
            #noUpdate
            {
                margin: 0 auto;
                font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
                font-size: x-small;
                color: #cccccc;
                text-align: left;
                width: 210px; 
                height: 200px;  
                padding: 5px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>  
        <div id="media">
            <div id="noUpdate">
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var so = new SWFObject( "lesson01.swf", "csSWF", "800", "618", "8", "#1a1a1a");
            so.addParam( "quality", "best" );
            so.addParam( "allowFullScreen", "false" );
            so.addParam( "scale", "noscale" );
            so.addParam( "allowScriptAccess", "always" );
            so.addVariable( "autostart", "false" );
            so.write("media");          
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Try opening it in Firefox](http://www.pclinuxos.com/forum/index.php?topic=105834.0). It seems to work out well.

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1:** Use Google Chrome (more straightforward). [Download it here](https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/desktop/).

**Option 2:** Use another web browser such as Mozilla Firefox, and install the flash plugin (from [omgubuntu.co.uk](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/11/install-adobe-flash-ubuntu)):

1. Open Software & Updates.
2. Switch to ‘Other Software‘ tab.
3. Click/check the ‘Canonical Partners’ repository.
4. Refresh your software sources when prompted.
5. Install `adobe-flashplugin`